# Dynamic array implementation of stack

Tags: stack, time-complexity

A programmer wants to create a dynamic array implementation of stack where instead of using repeated doubling, a new array of size `n+10` is created every time the array cannot accommodate more elements.

For example, for inserting the first element, array of size `0+10=10` will be created. After inserting **10 elements**, for inserting the  **11th** element a new array of size `10+10=20` will be created and the previous array elements will be copied to this new array.

What is the **time complexity** of this stack implementation?

Answer (score 0):

After n insertions, the array will be O(n) sized, somewhere between n-10 to n+10.
Let's look at the last time the array was increased. Assuming the size of the array is n+10, the calculation goes as follows:

size change -> 10 insertions -> size change -> 10 insertions ....

n+10 -> 10 insertions -> n -> 10 insertions -> n-10 -> 10 insertions -> ... -> n-n = 0 sized

so far, for n insertions, we have total:

Σ(n - 10*i)  operations, Σ goes from i=-1 to n

we get n*n total run-time, now we divide by n to get the run-time of each insertion, so it becomes O(n), amortized run-time for each operation.

Answer (score 0):

To accommodate `n*10` elements the array has to grow `n` times, so this might seem to be `O(n)`. However, growing an array involves copying its elements to the new array, which required `10` copy operations the first time, `20` the second, and so on, until `n*10` the `n`th. So I would say this is O(n^2).